# How sort/optimize list of objects to avoid gl calls

Tags: three.js

I'm looking at the three.js code and notice it interates over all objects while drawing. This in turn then updates the GL context for each object. But if I have a bunch of objects sharing a material this is highly inefficient, since it might be interleaved with other objects.

How can I put my objects in an order to minimize the gl calls? I know which objects share properties, I just don't know how to tell three.js that information.

---

Update: I modified the three.js code and counted the updates. It is quite wasteful. Given one logical object with two materials, for each one I add to the scene it needs to swap programs twice. So for 100 such objects it will swap 200 times as opposed to the desired 2 swaps!

Answer (score 1):

What is "optimal" is case-specific, so your question is too general to be answered. State changes are not the only issue of concern.

three.js sorts opaque objects from front to back, and transparent ones from back to front. It renders transparent objects last.

If you set

```
renderer.sortObjects = false;
```

then objects will be rendered in the order they are added to the scene. Since you know what your objects are, this is your work-around.

You can also merge your geometry, or use `BufferGeometry` to reduce the number of draw calls.

You can get info about the renderer by inspecting `renderer.info` in the console (or see https://github.com/spite/rstats). That way, you don't have to hack the source.

three.js r.64

Comment: The question is how can I go about grouping the objects? I know for sure the objects of a similar material can be rendered together. Unfortunately none of these are static, thus can't be combined, and must be inside different scene objects (as they have their own transforms).

Comment: This is a common problem. I do my best to help you, and I can answer your three.js questions, but it is impossible for me to tell you how to group your objects.

Comment: I know how I want to group them, I'm just not sure of how to tell three.js that. That is, I see no ability to influence the order of objects in renderer.__webglObjects. I wrote a custom sorter and it does the correct grouping, but it's obviously not standard.

Comment: As I said in my answer, set `renderer.sortObjects = false;` and add the objects to the scene in the order you want them rendered.

Comment: I can't do that though. The logical objects are grouped together in packages of Object3d. Each is a pair, all the first pair members should be rendered first, then all the second pair members. I'm using the combined object to share a scaling and position matrix.